# Android java.lang.NullPointerException when using back arrow navigation from toolbar

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-toolbar

I have 3 activities A, B and C.

From activity A, I send an `Intent` to activity B.

Based on the content of the `Intent`, I display Image 1 or 2 in activity B.
From the same activity B I go to Activity C to display more information based on the same Intent.

From the navigation toolbar Back arrow from activity C to B, I have an error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException

Using the if statement I solved the error, but I can get back the same intent info to display the either the image 1 or 2 because the `Intent` is now `NULL`.

```
 // onCreate method in activity B

 // Get intent from Activity A
    Intent i = getIntent();
    String r = i .getStringExtra("myIntent");
    Class c= Response.Parse(r);
  if (c != null) {
        //show result in Activity B
        displayResult(c.IsValidate());
  }
```

Comment: Please show the full stacktrace and a [mcve]

Comment: You need to save the intent data before going to C form B and re-use that upon coming back to B from C.

Comment: Exception or more code would help to know the exact problem

Answer (score 0):

When you press the back button on toolbar, Start the previous activity by sending the necessary intent.

When you start the next Activity, call `finish()` for this to work. Otherwise you will have to override `newIntent()` method to handle passed intents.

Eg.. when you click back from C activity, do something like:

```
Intent newIntentforBActivity = new Intent();
newIntentforBActivity.putExtra("myIntent","yourdata");
startActivity(newIntentforBActivity);
finish();
```

Just send a new intent back with the necessary arguments. Logic to put your data is dependant on your Logic.